# change the build status to NOT_BUILT if a file exists in post build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I create a file in workspace for a specific type of branch during my compilation. If the file exists I want the change the built status to NOT_BUILT and skip  the job.

How can I do it through post build groovy script.

Answer (score 3):

The Groovy Postbuild plugin exposes a variable called `manager` which can be used to access Jenkins objects. See the plugin's wiki page for [details](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin#GroovyPostbuildPlugin-Usage).

To set the build result to `NOT_BUILT`, do this:

```
manager.build.result = hudson.model.Result.NOT_BUILT
```